# How to pass a QueryString value to SignalR server using Windows Form application

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I am developing real-time network application using SignalR. I have Web and Windows Form  clients. I am using QueryString to pass the parameter "param" from Web App client to server using this javascript:

```
         $(function () {
            //Set the hubs URL for the connection
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8089/signalr";                

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. Declare queryString param
            $.connection.hub.qs = "param" + urlParams['param'];
            $.connection.hub.start();
...
```

On server side i am using:

```
   public override Task OnConnected()
   {
        var queryStr = Context.QueryString["param"];

        if (queryStr == value )
           DoSmth();
        else DoSmth2();
   }
```

I need to pass parameter "param" using QueryString from Windows Form App. I need something like : `$.connection.hub.qs = "param" + urlParams['param'];` but for Windows Form app. How to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it. I found this: "We have a bug in our logic that builds the url. We'll fix this for 0.5.3." If you want to work around it for now you can append /signalr to the url:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/signalr", "a=b");
```

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/581

Comment: MSDN docs for the HubConnection constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj879494(v=vs.111).aspx